# select same data from two columns in a table, and using one sql statement to show all data

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

i'm a fresh man in sql area, and i have some question.

the table like below

```
Table Name:EM

ID    name    Birth   High
1     Tom     11/23   65
2     Mary    11/23   65
3     Bill    03/02   55
4     Liny    01/08   45
5     Kevin   05/16   50
6     Lee     05/16   50
```

but I only need data like below

```
ID    name    Birth   High
1     Tom     11/23   65
2     Mary    11/23   65
3     Kevin   05/16   50
4     Lee     05/16   50
```

and I used fool sql to get data like this

```
select * from em where birth = '11/23' and high = '65';
select * from em where birth = '05/16' and high = '50';
```

please teach me how to get result in one sql statement, thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean dynamically? If not, select * from em where (birth = '11/23' and high = '65') or (birth = '05/16' and high = '50');

Comment: DazzaL's answer was what I need  ^^  thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want IN

```
select * from em where (birth, high) in (('11/23','65'),('05/16','50'));
```

Answer (score 4):

use `OR` to combine them:

```
select * from em where (birth = '11/23' and high = '65') or (birth = '05/16' and high = '50');
```

Comment: thanks but not I hope. i had think about it but it still too long.

Comment: Why is this too long? The `in` statement you marked as the answer is no different.

Comment: by this way, I have to repeat key in "birth = '' and high = '' ", and it's just a example, but actually I had to select out a lot of data, i think everybody will feel dizzy if the example data is too much :D.
still thank your for pay time to help me ^^

Comment: @Keith It actually depends. If `birth` and `high` constraint always appear in pairs, then `IN` statement is simpler; otherwise, `OR` statement is more flexible. Since you only gave one example, I couldn't tell which is better in advance.

Comment: @HuiZheng sorry, my issue didn't clearly, and thanks for your exposition, they are very useful for me when i coding and search data ^^

Answer (score 1):

[You may start learning SQL from here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Use `IN` and `BETWEEN` for this [check tutorial for IN here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) and [check tutorial for BETWEEN here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

This could be your query

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE COL1 IN (DATE_HERE,ID_HERE) AND/OR COL2 IN (DATE_HERE,ID_HERE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IN operator is used for adding multiples values

select * from em where birth in ('11/23','05/16') and high in ('65','50');
```

Comment: This will also return rows where `birth = 11/23` and `high = 50`. Looking at the sample data, I doubt that that's what OP wants but we also can't be sure either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "or","in" operator

like this:

```
 select * from em 
 where 
  birth = '11/23' or birth = '05/16' 
  and high = '65' or  high = '50';
```